# Element exceeds column its in from Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i'm trying to make a bootstrap row with a title and a badge to the right.
To see what's happening see the image at the bottom of this post.

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="box workoutscontent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
            <h1 class="workouttitle">@workout.WorkoutTitle</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">
            <h1>
                @if (workout.Goal == "Afslanken")
                {<span class="label label-primary workoutlabel">Afslanken</span>}
                @if (workout.Goal == "Aankomen")
                {<span class="label label-success workoutlabel">Aankomen</span>}
                @if (workout.Goal == "Spiermassa opbouwen")
                {<span class="label label-warning">Spiermassa opbouwen</span>}
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr/>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>@workout.DescriptionShort</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css applied to it is

Title:

```
.workoutscontent h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
```

Label:

```
.workoutlabel {
    float: right;
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Why does the label go outside of the box I put it in?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: Just from a markup semantics perspective, you don't want your label in an H1.  That implies it is the title of the page, which is what your workout title appears to be.  H1s in bootstrap also have specific formatting applied to them.  I'd recommend removing that.  Additionally, you could look into wells or alerts in bootstrap to accomplish formatting your workout label.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#alerts.  You also might get more answers if you include this in a JSFiddle, so people can replicate your results.

Comment: @Trevor.Screws the 'label' here is actually a span with a label class.  Span being an inline element, it is perfectly valid HTML markup to use within an H1 tag.  Bootstrap's own examples in their documentation for labels show these spans placed within all the various heading tags including h1, h2, etc. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#labels

Comment: @RobertWade Not saying it isn't valid syntactically.  Just more of a semantic thing.  In general, you only want one h1 per page.  If you have multiple, then you lose the meaning of what that h1 is.  More of general guidance, rather than something that will solving his current problem.

Comment: Though, to be fair, my recommendation of looking into alerts for this section also have semantics associated with them that are outside of what OP is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you're facing is that the right column definition is not large enough for it's content, so you need to take some away from the left column and add to the right. Remember to shoot for 12 columns per row.

Also you don't need the float on the h1, just use Bootstrap's `text-right` class on the div, to align in right in the column.  Using a grid can help you eliminate using floats which can create extra styling work for you as it takes the elements out of the normal flow.

Below is an example showing your markup as is (structurally) and another version below it with a different column set up allowing room for the right hand column's content, as well as removing the float.  I've put a grey background on the columns so you can see what's happening there.

**In the column settings I changed it to:**

- **XS** Screens: 5/7
- **S** Screens: 6/6
- **M+** Screens: 7/5

```css
.workoutscontent h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.workoutlabel {
  float: right;
}

/* for demonstration purposes only */
div.row div {
  background: #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<code>Unmodified:</code>
<div class="box workoutscontent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
            <h1 class="workouttitle">Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">
            <h1>
                <span class="label label-primary workoutlabel">Afslanken</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr/>


<code>Fixed:</code>
<div class="box workoutscontent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-s-6 col-md-7">
            <h1 class="workouttitle">Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-s-6 col-md-5 text-right">
            <h1>
                <span class="label label-primary">Afslanken</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

BTW... `<span>` is perfectly acceptable markup within an `h1` as it is an inline element, so don't worry about that despite comments saying otherwise.  Bootstraps own documentation shows it done this way: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#labels

Answer (score 0):

instead of float:right on .workoutlabel class just simply add text-right class on

also replace col-xs-10 col-md-10 with col-xs-9 col-md-9 and col-2-xs col-2-md to col-xs-3 col-md-3